# Discord.js / JS - Sort an array of strings by descending if each string has an assigned number (level leaderboard)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
var svlist = [];
        var svlistname = [];
        let rankEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        message.guild.members.forEach(member =>{
            if(!xp[`${member.user.id}-${message.guild.id}`]){
                return;
            }
            svlist.push(member.user.id)
            svlistname.push(member.user.username)
        })
        console.log(`${xp[`${svlist[0]}-${message.guild.id}`].level}`)
        for(var i = 0; i < svlist.length; i++){
            rankEmbed.addField(`${svlistname[i]}`, `Level ${xp[`${svlist[i]}-${message.guild.id}`].level}`)
        }
        message.channel.send(rankEmbed)
        break;
```

I am making a leaderboard for levels, and I want to sort by level. Currently it's random because `forEacesvlist.push` is just choosing random members. How could I rewrite this so `svlist` gets sorted according to the user's level? (Level number is `xp['${member.user.id}-${message.guild.id}'].level`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very easily with the **Array.sort()** function. But you need to change the way you store your values. This is a better and proper way:

```js
var leaderboard = [];
let rankEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
    if(!xp[`${member.user.id}-${message.guild.id}`]){
        return;
    }
    leaderboard.push({
        name: member.user.username,
        level: xp[`${member.user.id}-${message.guild.id}`]
    });
});
// Sort the leaderboard
leaderboard.sort((memberA, memberB) => {
    // Return the member who has the highest level
    return memberB.level - memberA.level;
}).forEach((member) => {
    rankEmbed.addField(member.name, `Level: ${member.level}`);
});

message.channel.send(rankEmbed)
break;
```